# Multiple targets named 'CSQLite' when building Swift project including package SQLite.swift on Linux

Tags: swift, linux, sqlite, vapor

Writing experimental Swift application which reads from a SQLite file. I'm using [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) to do it.

It builds and runs fine in Xcode as well as SPM on macOS Ventura (13) but now I'm wanting it to run on a Raspberry PI (Raspberry Pi OS). When I try to build it I get the following error:

> warning: 'csqlite': ignoring declared target(s) 'CSQLite' in the system package
> error: multiple targets named 'CSQLite' in: 'csqlite', 'sqlite-nio'; consider using the `moduleAliases` parameter in manifest to provide unique names.

Looking in Package.swift for SQLite.swift, I see the lines at the end:

```swift
#if os(Linux)
package.dependencies = [
    .package(url: "https://github.com/stephencelis/CSQLite.git", from: "0.0.3")
]
package.targets.first?.dependencies += [
    .product(name: "CSQLite", package: "CSQLite")
]
#endif
```

That repository consists of another package file:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:4.0
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "CSQLite",
    providers: [.apt(["libsqlite3-dev"])]
)
```

and a Module.modulemap file containing:

```
module CSQLite [system] {
    header "/usr/include/sqlite3.h"
    link "sqlite3"
    export *
}
```

**How to solve this?**

*Additional information after experimentation*
I stripped my project down to the basics. This is the package file.

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.7
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "WaterTank",
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-sqlite-driver.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "4.0.0")),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git", branch: "master"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .executableTarget(
            name: "Recorder",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "SQLite", package: "SQLite.swift", moduleAliases: ["CSQLite": "BSQLite"]),
            ]
        ),
    ]
)
```

And this is (now) the only source file:

```swift
import Foundation
import SQLite

@main
struct Recorder
{
    static func main()
    {
    }
}
```

When I try to build, sometimes I get this message…

```
warning: 'csqlite': ignoring declared target(s) 'CSQLite' in the system package
error: multiple targets named 'CSQLite' in: 'csqlite', 'sqlite-nio'; consider using the `moduleAliases` parameter in manifest to provide unique names
```

And sometimes I get this…

```
/home/pi/Programming/watertank/.build/checkouts/SQLite.swift/Sources/SQLite/Core/Backup.swift:32:8: error: no such module 'CSQLite'
```

as though the module name had changed, but now the (imported) parent module can't find it.

Surely I'm making a simple mistake somewhere?

*If you're tempted to ask me why I'm importing both Vapor & SQLite.swift, it's because I'm wanting two different but connected products in the one package as a learning exercise.*

Comment: Maybe you can find some relevant information in the [moduleAliases](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/main/Documentation/ModuleAliasing.md) documentation

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I spent a day digesting the documentation and experimenting, unfortunately without success. Have updated my question with the details.